# making sub director as root by htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, root

I made my new template as a root directory with help of .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !new/
RewriteRule (.*) /new/$1 [L]
```

but I have an issue with that, all the products images are on the default public_html. how can I access that and if I want to upload product image then i get this error

```
Not Found
The requested URL /new/pimgs/ was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

please help in this issue.

Comment: so you want to make `/new` as root folders except the pimgs folder?

Comment: yes but in the new template, images are called from pimgs, when new folder converted into root directory then my new template can't able to access the images.

Answer (score 0):

You should make an exclusion to check if the URI is not starting with `/pimgs/`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pimgs/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/new/
RewriteRule (.*) /new/$1 [L]
```

Line 1: Test if the request URI is not starting with /pimgs/

Line 2: Test if the request URI is not starting with /new/

Line 3: If line 1 and line 2 are fulfilled, rewrite the URL to `/new/$1`